# Is using a static method cheaper than importing the whole class?

Tags: java, import, static-libraries, static-methods

I have a small static method `mymethod` inside a relatively big (library) class `com.package.pirulo`. I can do one of two things: Either I import `com.package.pirulo` and then I just use `pirulo.mymethod(...)`, or I can use direclty the method with `com.package.pirulo.mymethod(...)`.

Which is cheaper from a resources/speed point of view? It looks like the second option is cheaper , but since `mymethod` can call other methods in `com.package.pirulo` maybe the whole library is always somehow imported anyway...

And: is the first option as expensive (same POV) as instantiating a `pirulo` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing makes absolutely no difference at runtime, and only a negligible (at most) difference at compile-time.

Comment: The point of using the static call is that I would be using a single method, instead of a whole big class. So from what you all told me, I think the compiler always imports the whole class. And makes sense, since the method could be using other fields/methods from the class. Thanks to all that answered!!

Comment: The compiler "imports" only what you tell it to. So it can be just a single method. But of course, at runtime, the whole class is loaded (and there is no difference at all if and how you imported it, the bytecode is exactly the same).

Comment: This was exactly my doubt, if calling the small method will load the big class at runtime. What a pity. :o) No one answered my second question, though...... Thanks!

Comment: @Kurru answered your second question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in performance with calling a static import vs using a fully qualified name.

Comment: "no difference in performance" *or otherwise*. The generated bytecode is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is very little difference between the two different methods of importing.

There are probably very few cases were you should really worry that much about object creation.

In the extreme micromanagement perspective, it is better to not make an object, but its not noticable typically.

Answer (score 1):

Import the class you need to use from the package.

The only time when you import **a single method** is on static imports, which no, don't save you time, and if they do, it's negligible, and you shouldn't be doing it for that reason anyway.

That said, sometimes static imports improve readability. For example, java.lang.String.format.

Answer (score 0):

The import statements only make code readable and easy to be written. After code has been compiled, all the references are replaced by fully qualified name and unused imports are ignored. `String s;"` will become `java.lang.String s;` automatically so its does not matter.

Comment: This is not really what I tried to ask. My doubt was between importing a big class, or only calling a small static method _inside_ that class. My only doubt was if calling the small method will import the whole class together with it. From the answers the people gave, I understand that this is the case.